# Calculate maximum datetime inside arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, datetime

I have documents like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5495f04088df2df349fd54cc"),
    "deleted" : "1",
    "packet" : [ 
        {
            "datetime" : ISODate("2014-12-20T21:54:08.278Z"),
            ...
        },
        {
            "datetime" : ISODate("2014-12-20T23:54:08.278Z"),
            ...
        },
        {
            "datetime" : ISODate("2014-12-20T20:54:08.278Z"),
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to update documents which the highest datetime inside the array is older than a certain datetime...

In SQL it would be something like:

```
update t1 set f1 = "whatever" where max(datetime) > date_add(now(), interval -5 minutes)
```

How can I do this in mongo on arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im pretty dang sure the defacto mongo `find` will search within arrays with any special jizz. the greater-than part is also simple.

```
db.documents.find("packet.datetime" : {$gt : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:05.000Z") } );
```

similarly you can update in one shot, make sure to use upsert false and multi true (in your case)

```
db.documents.update("packet.datetime" : {$gt : datetime },  
                  {f1: "whatever"}, {upsert: false, multi: true} );
```

that will match your target sql sans the interval thing-a-ma-bob

```
update t1 set f1 = "whatever" where max(datetime) > date_add(now(), 
       interval -5 minutes)
```

update: given your comment, you might need "not less than" vs "gt than"

```
db.documents.find("packet.datetime" :
              {$not: {$lt : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:05.000Z") } } );
```

it will select docs based on **all** datetimes in the array

Comment: thanks for the answer. OK, that's how i'm doing it now, but i wanted to make sure the date comparison is being done against the highest datetime inside the array... (btw it is $lt) Because there might be datetimes inside the array before the datetime i'm comparing, and other might be later... and i want ALL datetimes inside the array to be older than N...